# How to plant kinda file before building app and access it in react-native

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-fs

I make ios, android apps with react-native.

I'm looking for method that I can plant some file in project before I build the app, and access it after it would be run.

I know some modules like "RNFetchBlob" or "react-native-fs". so I can create, read and write some files
but I've no any idea with put it in app before it would be built.

How can I put a file in before the app would be run?
Can I get some clues or sample code about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer myself. so I share it.

it's the solution for ios

### Attaching Files or directory you want to react-native ios app project

run xcode > 
open your project ([react-native project]/[ios]) > 
right click on project that you can see at top of left side. >

select "Add Files to "[your project name]"
[image]

then choose files or directory that you wanna plant in app. > 
check "Copy items if needed" > 
click Add button
[image]

then you can see it included at left side window
[image]

### Accessing attached file with RNFetchBlob

you can access attached file path in your ios app via [RNFetchBlob FileSystem](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#dirs)

install that module to your react-native project like following command
`$ yarn add rn-fetch-blob`

then you can access the file like below code.

```js
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

const attachedFile = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.MainBundleDir}/androidVoiceRecord.m4a` ;
```